# Stack Overflow query not returning all data

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer

This is the first time I have tried querying the SO dataset so I may not be doing it correctly.

```
SELECT CreationDate, ViewCount,  Tags, ClosedDate , id
  FROM Posts
```

returns to me a datagrid headed thus

[image]

which is confirmed when opened locally. Over half the 50,000 rows have no values for `ViewCount` or `Tags`.

When I directly enter a specific ID where there is no `ViewCount` data, such as:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537179
```

I get redirected to

[Dictionary int:variable(reference) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536389/dictionary-intvariablereference-in-python/27537179#27537179)

where there are ViewCounts and tags present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Posts table contains all questions *and answers* (and some other types of posts, like tag wikis). Only questions can have a ViewCount, Tags, and ClosedDate. Answers do not have any of those.

Try modifying your query to only select questions (PostTypeId = 1):

```
SELECT CreationDate, ViewCount, Tags, ClosedDate, Id
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
```

Comment: As it happens, SO database contains [one answer with a tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/225495). A mystery...

Comment: @Fundamental Interesting. Have no idea how that one happened.